# How to add Bootstrap class in drupal contact form

Tags: css, module, drupal-7

I'm using drupal's default contact module. It is good for beginners like me but i'm OK with style. Is there any way to add style into contact form module in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add CSS in any module. For customizing the style you can style the form elements in your theme's CSS.

Comment: Is it possible to add bootstrap CSS in contact form module

Comment: You can use template_preprocess_page in your theme's template.php file to manipulate the UI related arguments.

Comment: Can you explain in detail, I'm not familiar with  template_preprocess_page

Comment: I'm wondering why i cannot find the HTML tag for contact form module. In fact where it is placed in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestion, But I would like to add bootstrap class in Drupal's contact module.